# Clang Error on "Potential null dereference."

Tags: cocoa, clang-static-analyzer

I keep getting Clang errors on the following type of code and I can't figure out why they're erroneous or how to resolve them to Clang's satisfaction:

```
+ (NSString *)checkForLength: (NSString *)theString error: (NSError **)error {
    BOOL hasLength = ([theString length] > 0);
    if (hasLength) return theString;
    else {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ErrorDomain" code:hasLength userInfo:nil];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Leaving aside the utterly-contrived nature of the example (which Clang did object to so it's illustrative enough), Clang balks at the error assignment line with the following objection:

> Potential null dereference. According to coding standards in 'Creating and Returning `NSError` Objects' the parameter 'error' may be null.

I like having a pristine Clang report. I've read the cited document and I can't see a way to do what's expected; I checked some open-source Cocoa libraries and this seems to be a common idiom. Any ideas?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The way to do what's expected is shown in listing 3-5 in that document.  With your example code:

```
+ (NSString *)checkForLength: (NSString *)theString error: (NSError **)error {
    BOOL hasLength = ([theString length] > 0);
    if (hasLength) return theString;
    else {
        if (error != NULL) *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ErrorDomain" code:hasLength userInfo:nil];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: I used a million times `if (error) *error = …` instead, without any crashes or analyser errors/warnings. Can I keep going this way?

Comment: Yes, the explicit equivalence of a null pointer to 0 and false is something objective C kept from plain old C.  I personally think it's bad style, but yeah you can simply use `if (error)` if you really want to.

Comment: NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Profile" code:100 userInfo:dictionary];

    if (error) {
        *perror = error;
    }
     I'm still getting a static analyzer warning on that *perror = error line

Comment: Well why on earth are you doing that? If the output parameter is `perror` then the variable in the `if` guard needs to be `perror` as well, as in:
    NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Profile" code:100 userInfo:dictionary];
    if (perror) {
        *perror = error;
    }
But I don't understand why you're introducing a new variable `error` here; just set it inside the `if`.

Comment: I don't understand why we have to check `error` *isn't* nil instead of *is* nil... Surely a null pointer is being sent into the method?

Comment: Sorry, I get it now... It has to check in case the object being passed in is just nil. Nothing to see here, move along...

Answer (score 17):

The Cocoa convention is that the return value should indicate success or failure (in this case, you return nil for failure) and the error is filled in with additional information, but only when the caller requests it.

In other words

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *result = [self checkForLength: aString error: &error];
```

and

```
NSString *result = [self checkForLength: aString error: NULL];
```

are both valid ways to invoke the method. So the method body should always check for a NULL error param:

```
if (error != NULL)
    *error = ...;
```

Comment: Actually, if the clang static analyser doesn't complain about your second snippit, I'd file a bug :-)

Comment: Are you referring to the snippet where NULL is passed for the error param? This is a documented pattern for using NSError. See <http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC>.

Comment: If I could've marked two answers, I would have. Thanks for explaining the context in which it might happen!

Comment: By the way, is it valid to pass in nil instead of NULL? Both values are equal to (void *)0 — that's at least what preprocessed Objective-C files say.