# What is the memory management problem with this bit of code?

Tags: ios, memory-management, coding-style

The XCode analyzer tells me there is a problem at line 4 — `return [originalError copy];` — but I don't see it. Help me please?

```
- (NSError *)errorFromOriginalError:(NSError *)originalError error:(NSError *)secondError
{
    if (secondError == nil) {
        return [originalError copy];
    }
    // ...
}
```

The problem description is:

- Potential leak of an object allocated on line 203

  - Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)
  - Object returned to caller as an owning reference (single retain count transferred to caller)
  - Object allocated on line 203 is returned from a method whose name ('errorFromOriginalError:error:') does not contain 'copy' or otherwise starts with 'new' or 'alloc'.  This violates the naming convention rules given in the Memory Management Guide for Cocoa (object leaked)
- Potential null dereference.  According to coding standards in 'Creating and Returning NSError Objects' the parameter 'error' may be null

The third issue seems to suggest I should either change the name or the behaviour of the method further. Any suggestions on that? The method is derived from the `errorFromOriginalError:error:` method described in [Apple's Core Data Validation document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html). Its purpose is to combine `originalError` and `secondError` so that `secondError` is a sub-error of `originalError`.

My addition tries to ensure that the method still works if there is no actual `secondError`. Since a new error object is created if `secondError` is not `nil`, I wanted to recreate that in the case displayed above by simply copying the error object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a copy of originalError, but your function name implies that the returned object will be autoreleased. Try

```
return [[originalError copy] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thank you, that did indeed fix the issues, except for the last one (potential null dereference). How do I get rid of that one? I tried adding `    if (originalError == nil)
        return nil;` at the beginning of the method, but to no avail.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189518/clang-error-on-potential-null-dereference/1189570#1189570

Comment: Merci. (I wonder if it's frowned upon to add "Thank you" comments on SO. I think it's polite, but what does the community think?)

Comment: No idea, I'm new here myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

`[originalError copy]` creates a new object with a retain count set to 1.  It would then be the responsibility of the calling method to `release` that object.  If you're doing this then it isn't necessarily a problem, but it's probably a better ideas to autorelease it.

ie

```
return [[originalError copy] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it is as correct as jrturton's. I hope you don't mind me marking his as correct, as he was slightly faster to answer.